# Optimization of a query with repeated info

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I have this query that I want to optimize

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ComprobantesFacturasObtenerEstadisticasLocal2] 
(
    @FechaDesde DateTime,
    @FechaHasta DateTime,
    @XML ntext  
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @docHandler INT

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandler OUTPUT, @XML    

    --Locales
    Select IdLocal
    into #seleccionados
    FROM OPENXML(@docHandler, N'/NewDataSet/Table1', 2) 
    WITH (IdLocal int)  

    select d.* into #Locales from  Dim_Sucursal d inner join GrimRepCen..Locales l on l.Codigo = d.Codigo inner join #seleccionados s on s.IdLocal = l.iDlocal

    /*2011/12/06 busco los descuentos del rio*/
    select distinct l.Codigo + ' - ' + l.Nombre  as local, c.IdComprobante, -1 as Cantidad,
        -1 * isnull(abs(c.TotalNeto),0) as IMPORTE, 
        'Varios' as Familia, 'Dto Bco Rio' as Linea
    into #descuentoRio
    from Fact_Comprobante(nolock) c 
    --inner join Fact_ComprobanteItem(nolock) ci on ci.IdComprobante = c.IdComprobante 
    inner join #locales l  on c.idDim_ComprobanteTipo = 5  and l.IdDim_sucursal = c.IdDim_sucursal  and c.fecha between @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta   

    /*******************COMPROBANTES************************************************ */
    select distinct
        c.*, l.Codigo + ' - ' + l.Nombre  as local, ct.IdComprobanteTipo
    into #Comprobantes
    from Fact_Comprobante(nolock) c 
    inner join Fact_ComprobanteItem(nolock) ci on ci.IdCOmprobante = c.IdComprobante
    inner join Dim_ComprobanteTipo(nolock) ct on ct.IdDim_ComprobanteTipo = c.idDim_ComprobanteTipo 
    inner join #locales l on l.IdDim_sucursal = c.IdDim_sucursal and  ct.IdComprobanteTipo not in (46 /*Error Fiscal Factura B*/, 47 /*Error Fiscal Factura A*/) and c.fecha between @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta   

     --Comprobantes por Linea/Marca/Familia
    select 
        m.Nombre as Marca, l.Nombre as Linea , case  when c.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) then 0 else -sum(ci.Cantidad) end as Cantidad,
        case  when c.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) 

        --toma en cuenta los descuentos de las facturas que fueron anuladas
        then c.TotalNeto 
        else isnull(ci.ImporteNeto,0) - isnull((select sum(importe) as importe 
                                                from Fact_Descuento (nolock) DD
                                                where DD.IdComprobante = ci.idComprobante  and ci.IdDim_Producto = IdDim_Producto
                                                 and ci.IdDim_Medida = IdDim_Medida and ci.IdDim_Calidad = IdDim_Calidad 
                                                 and exists 
                                                     (
                                                        select 1 
                                                        from ComprobanteReferencias AA
                                                        inner join Fact_Comprobante BB on aa.IdComprobanteCredito = BB.IdComprobante
                                                        where AA.IdComprobanteDebito = DD.IdComprobante
                                                        and BB.IdDim_ComprobanteTipo in (4,13,16,19)
                                                     )
                                                 ),0)
        end as IMPORTE, 
        f.Nombre as Familia
    from #Comprobantes c 
    inner join Fact_ComprobanteItem(nolock) ci on  ci.IdComprobante = c.IdComprobante 
    inner join Dim_Producto(nolock) p on p.IdDim_Producto = ci.IdDim_Producto
    inner join Dim_Marca(nolock) m on m.IdDim_Marca = p.IDDim_Marca
    inner join Dim_Familia(nolock) f on f.idDim_Familia = p.IdDim_Familia
    inner join Dim_Linea(nolock) l on l.IdDim_Linea = p.IdDim_Linea
    Group by m.Nombre,l.Nombre,f.Nombre,c.TotalNeto,ci.IdComprobante, ci.IdDim_producto,
    ci.idDim_Medida,ci.ImporteNeto,c.IdComprobanteTipo  ,ci.IdDim_Calidad
    union all
    select 'Grimoldi' as Marca, Linea , - 1 Cantidad,
        IMPORTE, 
        Familia
    from #descuentoRio 

    --/*Familia*/
    select case  when c.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) then 0 else -isnull(sum(ci.Cantidad),0) end as Cantidad,
    case  when c.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) 

        --toma en cuenta los descuentos de las facturas que fueron anuladas
        then c.TotalNeto 
        else isnull(ci.ImporteNeto,0) - isnull((select sum(importe) as importe 
                                                from Fact_Descuento (nolock) DD
                                                where DD.IdComprobante = ci.idComprobante  and ci.IdDim_Producto = IdDim_Producto
                                                 and ci.IdDim_Medida = IdDim_Medida and ci.IdDim_Calidad = IdDim_Calidad 
                                                 and exists 
                                                     (
                                                        select 1 
                                                        from ComprobanteReferencias AA
                                                        inner join Fact_Comprobante BB on aa.IdComprobanteCredito = BB.IdComprobante
                                                        where AA.IdComprobanteDebito = DD.IdComprobante
                                                        and BB.IdDim_ComprobanteTipo in (4,13,16,19)
                                                     )
                                                 ),0)
        end as IMPORTE, 
        f.Nombre as Familia
    from #Comprobantes c 
    inner join Comprobantes(nolock) co on co.IdComprobante = c.IdComprobante
    inner join Fact_ComprobanteItem(nolock) ci on  ci.IdComprobante = c.IdComprobante 
    inner join Dim_Producto(nolock) p on p.IdDim_Producto = ci.IdDim_Producto
    full outer join Dim_Familia(nolock) f on f.idDim_Familia = p.IdDim_Familia
    Group by f.Nombre,ci.ImporteNeto,ci.IdComprobante, ci.IdDim_producto,
    ci.idDim_Medida,c.TotalNeto, c.IdComprobanteTipo    ,ci.IdDim_Calidad
    union all
    select  -1 as Cantidad,
        IMPORTE, 
        Familia
     from #descuentoRio 

    /*local*/
    select c.Local, case  when c.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) then 0 else -isnull((sum(ci.Cantidad)),0) end as Cantidad,
        case  when c.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) 

        --toma en cuenta los descuentos de las facturas que fueron anuladas
        then c.TotalNeto 
        else isnull(ci.ImporteNeto,0) - isnull((select sum(importe) as importe 
                                                from Fact_Descuento (nolock) DD
                                                where DD.IdComprobante = ci.idComprobante  and ci.IdDim_Producto = IdDim_Producto
                                                 and ci.IdDim_Medida = IdDim_Medida and ci.IdDim_Calidad = IdDim_Calidad 
                                                 and exists 
                                                     (
                                                        select 1 
                                                        from ComprobanteReferencias AA
                                                        inner join Fact_Comprobante BB on aa.IdComprobanteCredito = BB.IdComprobante
                                                        where AA.IdComprobanteDebito = DD.IdComprobante
                                                        and BB.IdDim_ComprobanteTipo in (4,13,16,19)
                                                     )
                                                 ),0)
    end as IMPORTE,
    f.Nombre as Familia, l.Nombre as Linea
    from #Comprobantes c 
    inner join Comprobantes(nolock) co on co.IdComprobante = c.IdComprobante
    inner join Fact_ComprobanteItem(nolock) ci on  ci.IdComprobante = c.IdComprobante 
    inner join Dim_Producto(nolock) p on p.IdDim_Producto = ci.IdDim_Producto
    inner join Dim_Linea(nolock) l on l.IdDim_Linea = p.IdDim_Linea
    inner join Dim_Familia(nolock) f on f.idDim_Familia = p.IdDim_Familia
    Group by f.Nombre,ci.ImporteNeto, l.Nombre  ,ci.IdComprobante, ci.IdDim_producto,
    ci.idDim_Medida, c.Local,c.TotalNeto, c.IdComprobanteTipo,ci.IdDim_Calidad
    union all
    select Local, -1 as Cantidad,
        IMPORTE, 
        Familia, Linea
     from #descuentoRio 
end
```

There are some things that I cannot change, for example, sending the id's in other way instead of xml (because I'd have to modify the code and I can't), the structure of the tables and other stuff. I can only modify this stored.
This query recieves some Id's, insert in a temporal Table (`#Seleccionados`) and use it to do some Joins to get info about sales and others.
Also, you can see weird things, as an Union ALL with harcoded values, and other things. That's because the way the report in the code was done, and also cannot change that (I mean, don't worry for that weird things).
This stored basically returns 4 selects: One of them it's just one row, so I got the problem with the other 3, that I'm showing you here.

**What I've tried:**

What I was thinking was try to solve some things that are repetead, for example, this subquery:

```
(select sum(importe) as importe 
                                                from Fact_Descuento (nolock) DD
                                                where DD.IdComprobante = ci.idComprobante  and ci.IdDim_Producto = IdDim_Producto
                                                 and ci.IdDim_Medida = IdDim_Medida and ci.IdDim_Calidad = IdDim_Calidad 
                                                 and exists 
                                                     (
                                                        select 1 
                                                        from ComprobanteReferencias AA
                                                        inner join Fact_Comprobante BB on aa.IdComprobanteCredito = BB.IdComprobante
                                                        where AA.IdComprobanteDebito = DD.IdComprobante
                                                        and BB.IdDim_ComprobanteTipo in (4,13,16,19)
                                                     )
                                                 )
```

in the `ISNULL` Clause is repeated for the 3 selects. So, I thougt that I could use WITH Common_Expresion_Table and reduce it. But, that select, its a subquery, so depends from values from the select when I use the subquery (can see what I'm Saying in the `where` clause of that subquery)

Then I though, the 3 selects there are not so different. They have a couple of Joins repeated, but grouped by different way. So, I also thougt of using some kind of Temporally Table or CTE, but I'm not sure about that because they are grouped from different way, and also have one or two differents `JOINS`

*Some extra info:*

`#Seleccionados` will have like 100 rows of Id's.
This query takes 50 segs. For a week:

- The first query returns `47083 rows`
- The second query returns `47084 rows`
- The third query returns `47084 rows`

as you can see, it's almost the same information, grouped by a different way.

Tables:
`Fact_Comprobante` got info about one sale. `Fact_ComprobanteItem` about the items of the sale.
`Dim_Producto` got info about one product, `Dim_Familia` info about families of products, `Dim_Marca` got info about Signs of products, `Dim_Linea` got info about the Lines of products (these 3 tables are FK in Dim_Producto).
`Dim_ComprobanteTipo` got info about the types of sales
`Fact_Descuento` got info about discounts, related to sales.

All tables got a lot of info.

The `(Nolock)` statements are because we have 3 services inserting, updating and other stuff at the same time in these tables.

I didn't do this query, I just have to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL profiler (if you have access to it) and filter for the name of the stored procedure. Make sure you are displaying every step (so running the procedure gives more then 1 or 2 rows). Then on every step you'll see the nr of seconds, the nr of reads, writes etc.. So then you can focus into the time consuming parts.

Alternative you could use this SQL profiling alternative:

```
declare @dStart datetime
set @dStart = getdate()

-- at every place you like to monitor
print 'a: ' + convert(nvarchar(datediff(ms, @dStart, getdate()))
```

Without diving into the procedure I would start at the subquery 
    and exists 
    (
        ...

that is probably an expensive one, rather rewrite that to a left or right join

Comment: thanks for the answer ! I had recently modify the stored, and now is 20 segs more faster. I have combine the first and third select in one temp table, and then select grouping by different fields. I know I have to modify the ISNULL statement, but I don't know how to. Right now, there are no more money (budget? sorry my bad english) so I will see this later.